# ArrayList with 2 dimensions

Tags: java, arraylist

```
private static ArrayList<String>[][] table;

public boolean processString(String w)
{
    int length = w.length(); //w= "aabaa"
    table = new ArrayList[length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        table[i] = new ArrayList[length];
        for (int j = 0; j < length; ++j)
            table[i][j] = new ArrayList< String >();
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what exactly this code is doing? And what are the two square brackets for in the declaration of the ArrayList? Is that a 2 dimensional ArrayList?

Comment: What do you want from this code?

Comment: `table` is probably of type `ArrayList[][]`, otherwise the code won't compile.

Comment: Try to elaborate a bit this code

Comment: @Abdelhak This is a part of the implementation of the CYK algorithm. This code is making the matrix i think. This is also a part of the code that i forgot to mention: private static ArrayList<String>[][] table;

Comment: This creates a 2d matrix of `length X length` with `length` being `w.length()`.

Comment: @Tom Okay, I got that. But if this is a 2 dimensional ArrayList, then what do they mean by table[i] = new ArrayList[length]; ? This gets one dimensional, what position is table[i] ?

Comment: Well, it has 3 dimensions, because the array itself has two, but the ArrayList adds the third dimension. `table[i] = new ArrayList[length];` since a 2d array is just an array of arrays, you need to initializes the _inner_ array. That what happens there.

Comment: @Tom That helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically trying to make a two-dimensional ArrayList.
Your table is two -dimensional array list as you have mentioned:

```
ArrayList<String>[][] table;
```

Comment: A two-dimensional ArrayList would be `ArrayList<String>[]`, not `ArrayList<String>[][]`.

Comment: @Tom a one-dimensional array is `ArrayList<String>[]` source: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mrmiller/15-110/Handouts/arrays2D.pdf

Comment: @RichardJones We are not talking about Arrays, we are talking about ArrayList and the list itself is the first dimension. The second dimension is an array of ArrayList and what we have here is an array of arrays of ArrayList.